# How to create an ADBUDG Economics Marketing Model with R

Tags: r, google-analytics, analytics

So I am trying to recreate [this blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/industries/media-and-entertainment/your-paid-search-is-cannibalizing-your-natural-search-use-r-to-predict-how-much-you-should-be-spending/), but the author does not give very detailed steps for use with **R**.

So, I have [this set of data](http://pastebin.com/rA5pSMzr) which contains total paid search spend, branded spend, non-branded spend, paid clicks (marked simply as clicks), organic visits, total visits, visitors and transactions for an ecommerce site.

I attempted to do the first part by myself and was given this output:

```
> fit <- lm(organic.visits ~ visits + clicks +visitors + transactions, data=mydata)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = organic.visits ~ visits + clicks + visitors + transactions, 
    data = mydata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5916.6 -1100.9  -237.4   811.6  8444.0 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7028.56997  502.55911  13.986  < 2e-16 ***
visits          1.15842    0.04406  26.295  < 2e-16 ***
clicks          0.46578    0.09884   4.712 3.39e-06 ***
visitors       -1.13322    0.04442 -25.513  < 2e-16 ***
transactions   -1.11505    0.19823  -5.625 3.49e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1903 on 399 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8236,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8219 
F-statistic: 465.8 on 4 and 399 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

First: I want to know if I did this correctly, or if there is a better way to do it.

Second: I want to know how to do the second part of the post which is the ADBUDG Economics Marketing Model. I tried to search online, but have not found anything useful in helping meet complete this part of the analysis. The author does not give any direction on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to set natural search clicks as your independent variable - to the left of the "~" - and have the others be the dependent variables (of which paid search clicks should be one).

Then take a look at the estimate for paid search clicks to see how they're affecting natural search.

To find the best estimates of the ADBUDG model parameters, you'll need to use some kind of solver.  First create the equation (b + (a-b) * spend^c / (d + spend ^ c)), then calculate the error from each point by subtracting the ADBUDG predictions from the actuals.  Then you can use Excel's solver or a solver in R to find the a, b, c, and d that minimize the total squared error.

a gives you the upper bound, and b gives your the lower bound based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that your response variable (or dependent variable), in this case, organic visits is a continuous variable. If so, then your model is correct. However, it is always needed to cheeck for model assumptions, such as the distribution of the residuals and their homocedasticity. You can visualize that by using:

```
plot(fit)
```

Regarding results interpretation. Each one of the predictive variables (or independent variables) show a significant effect. If these variables are also continuous, this means that each one of this variables have a relationship with the response variable which is statistically different from 0. For instance, in the case of the variable "visits", we expect that, for an increase of 1.15 in visitors we would expect an increase of 1 in organic visits. The effect is negative when estimates are smaller than zero.

You can see that by including the individual effect of these variables, you can explain the 82% of the variance in your response variable (see R squared).

Cheers!

Pablo